# Equivalence of two statements regarding distributive lattices

Tags: lattice-orders

I've two statements.

> $(i)$   A lattice L is distributive if and only if it has
> no sublattice isomorphic to $M_3$ and $N_5$
> $(ii)$   L is distributive if and only if $z ∧ x = z ∧ y$ and $z ∨ x = z ∨ y$ imply that $x = y$.

Why are these two statements equivalent?

Comment: They're equivalent because they're both true. If two sentences have the same logical value, then they're equivalent. If you want a proof of each of those two equivalences, that's something else.

Comment: if they are said to be equivalent, then obviously they are. my question is how they are equivalent.

Comment: The statements are equivalences. Equivalences are either true or false. If they're both true or both false, then they are equivalent. You asked how are these equivalent, not why are these true, which would be to prove each of the statements.

Comment: ok... edited.. thanks @amrsa

Comment: Again, do you really want to know why two true statements are equivalent? That's rather obvious. Perhaps you'd like to know why are they true, instead?

Comment: I want to know why these two statements are equivalent. Meaning I want a proof that each implies the other.

Answer (score 2):

First, consider to prove, or check some known proof, of the first statement.
You can find it (among many other places) in [this book](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Esnburris/htdocs/UALG/univ-algebra2012.pdf), Theorem 3.6, in the first chapter.

Now, you can easily find elements both in $N_5$ and in $M_3$ which violate that implication (you don't have to search much since they only have five elements each).

For the converse, it will be enough to prove that for every distributive lattice $L$, if for every $a,b,c \in L$, we have $a \wedge b = a \wedge c$ and $a \vee b = a \vee c$, then we also have that $b = c$.
Now, under the conditions,

\begin{align}
b 
&= b \wedge (a \vee b)\\
&= b \wedge (a \vee c)\\
&= (a \wedge b) \vee (b \wedge c)\\
&= (a \wedge c) \vee (b \wedge c)\\
&= (a \vee b) \wedge c\\
&= (a \vee c) \wedge c\\
&= c,
\end{align}
where I suppose you can justify each step.

Comment: this book is really helpful. thanks...